# How to make a dijit.Dialog nonmodal

Tags: javascript, dojo

I want to make my dialogs non-modal, i.e.:

- When opening multiple dialogs, they could be closed in any order (modal dialogs can only be opened in the reverse order in which they were opened)
- Clicking a dialog puts it above the others

I've been reading the dojo/dijit documentation and found nothing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is dojox.layout.FloatingPane.